# Contador basado en texto dentro de celdas de una tabla

Tags: jquery

Tengo una tabla actualizada por Ajax y recibo valores diferentes en algunas celdas. Quiero hacer un contador si algunos valores coinciden. Tengo una función que lo hace pero el contador no muestra el nuevo valor hasta que refresco la página entera. ¿Que puedo hacer? Aprecio su ayuda y tiempo chicos.

Esta es mi función:

```
var consCount = 0;
$(function() {
$("#pizarra #trPizarra").each(function(){
    var estado = $(this).find('#tdEdo').text();
    var asunto = $(this).find('#tdImg').text();
    var juntos = estado + asunto;

if(juntos === "listo" + "0" || juntos === "listo" + "4"){ ++consCount; }
});

setInterval(function(){    
$('#count-consulta-span').load(document.URL +  ' #count-consulta-span',function(){
    $('#count-consulta-span').text(consCount);
        });
},3500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Error:

> Ejecutas el `script` contador, únicamente en el `onload`.

Solución:

Podrías crear una función (`contador`) y llamarla cada vez que se actualiza la tabla.

Por ejemplo:

```
$(function() {

  function contador() {
    var consCount = 0;
    $("#pizarra #trPizarra").each(function() {
      var estado = $(this).find('#tdEdo').text();
      var asunto = $(this).find('#tdImg').text();
      var juntos = estado + asunto;

      if (juntos === "listo0" || juntos === "listo4") {
        ++consCount;
      }
    });
    return consCount;
   }

  setInterval(function(){
    $('#count-consulta-span').load(document.URL +  ' #count-consulta-span',function(){
      $('#count-consulta-span').text(contador());
    });
  },3500);
});
```